# Where can I get information on the ! operator used by VB.Net in Linq to DataSet?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, operators, linq-to-dataset

The [Sample Queries application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397989(v=vs.90).aspx) uses a ! operator to reference a field in the DataRow.

```vb
Option Strict Off

Imports System.Data
Imports System.Linq

Module Program

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim numbers() As Integer = {5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0}
        Dim table As New DataTable("Numbers")
        table.Columns.Add("number", GetType(Integer))
        For Each n In numbers
            table.Rows.Add(New Object() {n})
        Next

        Dim lowNums = From row In table.Rows _
                      Where row!number < 5
                      Select row

        For Each x In lowNums
            Console.WriteLine(x!number)
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

What is the ! operator called? 
Where are the rules documented?

Comment: You are doing yourself a disservice by turning `Option Strict Off`.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, I agree with your opinion. This was a purely academic question, and it depends on Option Strict Off. Otherwise you must use row.Field(Of Integer)("number")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is (in this context) the [Exclamation point Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxda45fy.aspx):

*"Use the ! operator only on a class or interface as a dictionary access operator. The class or interface must have a default property that accepts a single String argument. The identifier immediately following the ! operator becomes the argument value passed to the default property as a string."*

so  the  code `row!number` is equivalent to `row("number")`

This operator is a legacy carryover from VB6 and should be avoided in VB.NET IMO. It is not really related to LINQ specifically.

<s>Your example is a little contrived as it doesn't compile (even with Option Strict Off)</s> - **Edit: this has now been amended but still won't compile with Option Strict Off**

note *"The ! character is also used as the Single type character."* e.g. `Dim s! = 0.12` but that is not the intention of the code in your context

Comment: thank you! I fixed my code sample. I should have compiled it before I published.
I think a better name is the dictionary access operator, or better yet the default string indexer property operator

Comment: Matt describes this well. 'x!y' is just a 'shortcut' for 'x("y")'